# Помогите укоротить функцию в javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function replaceNum() {

  if (count2 < 3) {
    count4 = 0;
  }else if(count2 >= 3 && count2 < 6) {
    count4 = 1;
  }else if (count2 >= 6 && count2 < 9) {
    count4 = 2;
  }else if (count2 >= 9 && count2 < 12) {
    count4 = 3;
  }else if (count2 >= 12 && count2 < 15) {
    count4 = 4;
  }else if (count2 >= 15 && count2 < 18) {
    count4 = 5;
  }else {
    count4 = 6;
  }

  count2 += 1;
}
```

Можно ли как нибудь переписать эту функцию с помощью цикла?

Comment: все переменные целые и положительные?

Comment: Вам нужен не цикл а целочисленное деление =)

Comment: В смысле целые?

Comment: в том смысле, что не с плавающей запятой.

Comment: Ща объясню, подождите)

Comment: да да! изначально они хранят 0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если вкратце, то согласно вашей логике цикл вам не нужен, и достаточно целочисленного деления:
Math.floor округляет результат до ближайшего меньшего целого.

```
function replaceNum() {
    count4 = Math.floor(count2/3);
    count2 += 1;
}
```

У этого кода есть ряд других стилистических проблем, но об этом мы вероятно поговорим в следующей серии)

Одна из этих проблем - именование переменных.
Не стоит называть переменные count2, count4. Старайтесь называть их как можно более осмысленно, это поможет когда будете в этом разбираться.

Название переменной обычно состоит из одного или нескольких английских слов написанных подряд. Чтобы отделить одно слово от другого, каждое следующее обычно называется с большой буквы. Такой стиль называется camelCase (верблюжья нотация)
Например

```
myAwesomeVariable = 15;
```

Собственно если изменить названия переменных в вашем коде до осмысленных, это будет например так. Разумеется это неоднозначно, Вы можете придумать свои красивые имена (в js можно кстати переменные по-русски называть но никогда-никогда-никогда их потом никому не показывайте =)); В любом случае это будет лучше чем count2, count4

```
function processCardIndexes() {
    cardStackIndex = Math.floor(cardTotalIndex/3);
    cardTotalIndex += 1;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать)))

Comment: "У этого кода есть ряд других стилистических проблем" Можете вкратце описать?

Comment: @Deniso, вот я потому и сразу не написал что долго объяснять. Вкратце - названия переменных плохие и вместо того чтобы работать с аргументами функции Вы работаете с какими-то переменными верхнего уровня. Про именование я пожалуй могу более-менее кратко написать

Comment: Всё приходит о опытом) Я пока что новичок в этом. А вам спасибо большое за помощь))))

Comment: @DenisoDeniso в общем я написал. Но на вашем уровне я бы рекомендовал не очень сильно заморачиваться вопросами стиля, а в первую очередь понимать логику алгоритма, который Вы хотите написать. Ну и не бойтесь спрашивать)

Comment: Просто бывают такие моменты что не всегда получается придумать имя переменной. Допустим переменные из моего кода(count* - counter) выступают в роле счетчиков, их пока что там 4.

Comment: @DenisoDeniso, это приходит с опытом. Каждый счетчик у вас имеет смысл. Вот count2 - это порядок карты в колоде, count4 - порядок карты в текущей стопке. Согласно этому смыслу и надо стараться назвать. Значительно проще написать coun2, count4, но значительно сложнее разобраться в том что написали, в том числе вам самому)

Comment: @DenisoDeniso плюс привычка задумываться над именами, помогает понять сам алгоритм, и думать в более ясных понятиях, чем абстрактные "счетчики" и "шаги"

Comment: а от куда вы узнали про карты?

Comment: @DenisoDeniso, я ваш предыдущий вопрос видел, просто у меня времени отвечать не было)

Comment: Спасибо за советы) Надеюсь еще ни раз спишемся))